# A2019: how to get a context menu in a form for an unbound date control like for bound date controls

Tags: controls, contextmenu, ms-access-2016, unbound

I'm not sure how it is possible to get the same contextmenu for an unbound form's control like for bound controls, both with a date value.

There are two unbound controls which get their control value via:

txtErsteSpende:

```
=Wenn([spSurrKey]>0;DomMin("[zaZahlDatum]";"[tblZahlungen]";"[zaSP_FKEY] = " & [Formulare]![frm110_Spender]![spSurrKey]);Null)
```

and

txtLetzteSpende:

```
=Wenn([spSurrKey]>0;DomMax("[zaZahlDatum]";"[tblZahlungen]";"[zaSP_FKEY] = " & [Formulare]![frm110_Spender]![spSurrKey]);Null)
```

Sorry for these are examples in german: "wenn" means "iif". It seems the bound control allows the context menu but not available for unbound controls.

Or is there a technique without writing vba-code to allow same context menu for both kind of controls?

Any suggestions appreciated
thx

[Contextmenu filter a date - bound control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h34Q.jpg)
[Contextmenu filter a date - unbound control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWLs0.jpg)

Comment: What does "A2019" refer to?

Comment: = Access Version 2019

Comment: Those Datumsfilter menu entries are used for the inbuilt data filtering in tables or bound forms. By definition this only applies to bound controls. What would you expect the menu items to do for unbound controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the goal was:

- make the form updatable
- display the date contextmenu for the two textboxes

After trying around with subforms which wasn't practable because the form is displayed in data sheet view I found this solution:

qry110:

```
SELECT tblSpender.spID, tblSpender.spNachname, tblSpender.spVorname, tblSpender.spOrt, tblSpender.spGebdat, DMin("[zaZahlungsdatum]","[tblZahlungen]","[zaSPFKEY] = " & Nz([tblSpender].[spID],0)) AS datErsteSpende, DMax("[zaZahlungsdatum]","[tblZahlungen]","[zaSPFKEY] = " & Nz([tblSpender].[spID],0)) AS datLetzteSpende
FROM tblSpender;
```

=> works fine but shows #Error in the form's textbox when in table tblZahlungen there is no entry (no ForeignKey) for the PrimaryKey in tblSpender

So I created a second query as recordsource for frm110 based on the first qry110 which checks the NULLvalue:

qry111:

```
SELECT qry110_Spender.spID, qry110_Spender.spNachname, qry110_Spender.spVorname, qry110_Spender.spOrt, qry110_Spender.spGebdat, IIf(Nz([datErsteSpende],0)>0,DateValue([datErsteSpende]),Null) AS datumErsteSpende, IIf(Nz([datLetzteSpende],0)>0,DateValue([datLetzteSpende]),Null) AS datumLetzteSpende
FROM qry110_Spender;
```

It works and now the form's recordset IS updatable.
Maybe the form isn't very performant for big data but it's acceptable for my users

thx for your hints

[contextmenu for date textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1k5c.jpg)